# How to add class to every element using html, css only?

Tags: html, css

I want to add class "responsive-table" to every table element in on my page. What should I do?

Comment: Go ahead and add `class="responsive-table"` to every `<table>` element on your page!

Comment: can you explain why ? as far as i know, coder has to code, so you have to add classes to the needed element ... it's like you said : *how should i write code without writing code*

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to take the time to do it, simply add `class="responsive-table"` between the carrots, like this for example:

`<tr class="responsive-table">`

But if you're already adding the same class to every part of your table with using only CSS, why don't you just put the CSS you want for 'responsive-table' in the table section?

i.e. instead of `.responsive-table {/* your css here */}`

you just do `table {/* your css here */}`?

Comment: Why would he add the class to a table row instead of the table itself?

Comment: @connexo It was just an example of how to add class to an html element, though you're right - `<table class="responsive-table">` would be more appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem using CSS only, go ahead as follows:

Find the CSS block that declares rules for `.responsive-table` which should start like this:

```
.responsive-table { /* rules here */ }
```

Then add the element selector for table elements to make sure **all** tables are matched:

```
.responsive-table, table { /* rules here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add them manually; there's no way to do that with just HTML and CSS, unfortunately. (Then again, if you could, they'd become just another Javascript...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all table become "`.responsive-table`" then why not applying all '`.responsive-table`' CSS code under `table` selector like following?

```
table { /* .responsive-table css here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add classes dynamically to every table element on your webpage by using html and css only. if you want to add class to every table on your webpage, you have to do that manually. or if you want to add same css to all tables on your webpage, try using 'table' element selector css as follows:

   `table { /* add your css here */ }`

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery

```
<script>
    $("table").addClass("responsive-table");
</script>
```

if you don't know how to use jquery
then just add this line in your head section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then put the code above on your page that where you want to add class.

Comment: but he said using only html/CSS

Comment: but I don't think it is possible. that's why I posted an alternative.